# Zero pad ndarray along axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to pad:

```
[[1, 2]
 [3, 4]]
```

to

```
[[0, 0, 0]
 [0, 1, 2]
 [0, 3, 4]]
```

I have no problem in doing so when input is 2D by vstack & hsrack

However, when I add 1 dim to represent the dim of number, such as:

```
img = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=(2, 2, 2))
```

**I cannot do so if I would not like to use for loop.
Is there any way to avoid for but only numpy's stack to make it?**

ps: for this example I should get (2,3,3) array by each 2 img instance is pad by zero at 1st column & 1st row.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.pad` and remove the last row/column:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
result = np.pad(a, 1, mode='constant', constant_values=0)[:-1, :-1]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 3 4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), which allows you to specify the number of values padded to the edges of each axis.

So for the first example `2D` array you could do:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
np.pad(a,((1, 0), (1, 0)), mode = 'constant')

array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 4]])
```

So here each tuple is representing the side which to pad with zeros along each axis, i.e. `((before_1, after_1), … (before_N, after_N))`.

---

And for a `3D` array the same applies, but in this case we must specify that we only want to `zero` pad the two last dimensions:

```
img = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=(2, 2, 2))
np.pad(img, ((0,0), (1,0), (1,0)), 'constant')

array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, -3, -2],
        [ 0,  9, -5]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  1, -9],
        [ 0, -1, -3]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pad only the column

```
import numpy as np

max_length =20
a = np.random.randint(1,size=(1, 10))
print(a.shape)
print(a.shape[1])
a =np.pad(a, [(0, 0), (0,  max_length - a.shape[1])], mode='constant')
print(a.shape)
```

Output

```
(1, 10)
10
(1, 20)
```