# Why is np.pad not working the way I expect it to?

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error

My code generates an array that is 4x2.
It also generates another array that is 10x6
I want to pad each array with zeros so that it is centered in an array that is 14x12 after padding.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html

```
a = some array 4x2
b = some array 10x6
c = np.pad(a, padder=0, 2, 'pad_width', padder=0))
```

TypeError: pad() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Why you have the parameter `padder=0` two times in your function call? You also have two closing brackets.

Comment: Artifact from playing around with the parameter order, following how others have done it in the past.

Comment: For a reference on how to pad a 2d array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076094/zero-pad-ndarray-along-axis/56076306#56076306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this you get an array with shape(14,12) with the smaller array centered.

```
source_array = np.random.rand(10,6)
target_array_shape = (14,12)

pad_x = (target_array_shape[0]-source_array.shape[0])//2
pad_y = (target_array_shape[1]-source_array.shape[1])//2
target_array = np.pad(source_array, ((pad_x,pad_x),(pad_y,pad_y)), mode="constant")
```

Obviously the centering can only be correct if the source array is smaller than the target array otherwise you get a `ValueError(index can't contain negative values)`.

Also the target dimension might not be correct if the target and source dimension, are not both even or both odd.

Comment: That is such a beautiful code! And it worked within the limitations you proposed. Thank you!